# Background Services for android O

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

For android O, the background services limitations are introduced. I learned about the firebase jobdispatcher that it can run as it is on android O like older versions. But when I run this code on android O, it response nothing and seems there is no job scheduling run in background. The same code is running smoothly in older versions. Can somebody tell me the new behavior of firebase jobdispatcher in android O. Furthermore, how background services run now in android O.

I attach a simple code where I try to generate a notification. I know about the notification channels and the notification is generated when I call the method **NotificationUtils.workerReminder(context)** but when I run in Service class nothing is happen and no notification is generated in android O.

Here is the scheduling code.

```
synchronized public static void remindJob(Context context) {
    if (isInitialized) return;

    Driver driver = new GooglePlayDriver(context);

    FirebaseJobDispatcher jobDispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

    Job job = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(Service.class)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(60, 120))
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setTag(JOB_TAG)
            .build();
    Log.d(Reminder.class.getSimpleName(), "after build the job");

    jobDispatcher.schedule(job);
    isInitialized = true;
}
```

This is Service class

```
public class Service extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
        backgroundTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                Context context = Service.this;
                NotificationUtils.workerReminder(context);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                jobFinished(job, false);
            }
        };

        backgroundTask.execute();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
        if (backgroundTask != null) backgroundTask.cancel(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks.